# How to hyperlink android html assets when using chrome client?

Tags: html, android, assets, webchromeclient

I have a main page (main.html) in the assets folder that I am displaying with:

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new VersionCallbackScript(), "demo");
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html");
```

and I want to put a link in the document to another html file in assets folder.  When I similiarly put in the tag:

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/secondpage.html">Touch here for page 2</a></font></h4>
```

and touch it in the client, the screen loads a blank page.

likewise, I want to have a table of contents that isA ListView and uses loadUrl with an html page suffixed with an anchor.  I tried and it is not working

```
String anchor = "subsection1";
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html" + "#" + anchor);
```

this construct is not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the following piece of code

```
<a href="secondpage.html">Touch here for page 2</a>
```

For me it does the job.

Comment: OMG - both forms are now working for me, but I have to thank you for trying it to verify.  You get the +50.  Thanks!

Comment: All devices working fine but in htc device not working